# UWP windows 10 app memory increasing on scroll listview and add item at the bottom of listview

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have UWP windows 10 app and noticed memory using by app increase when new `items` add at the end of `listview`, memory increase around **4MB** for each `item`.

I found that the increasing memory is because of the item template that i set for them. I used an `UserControl` for item template that contain some button and some textblock and 1 image.

How can Remove the item that are not on the screen visible from memory ?

The user Control is similar to this :

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="XamlPullToRefresh.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XamlPullToRefresh"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding myObject.imageUrl}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding myObject.name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding myObject.text}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Margin="10"/>
            <Button Margin="10"/>
            <Button Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: If you have a large image for the Image element of each item, this could be the problem, besides, ListView control has its own Virtualization mechanism, but I doubt that could help if Images are the problem.

Comment: Agree with @MehrzadChehraz, you can refer to [ListView and GridView data virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt574120.aspx), just tested your code, this problem didn't occur by my side. I tested over 700 items and the size of each picture is 145kb.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz yes it seems the main problem is `image`, I test the app without the image and the resualt is great. at the first without image i have 20 `item` and **50mb** and with image **190mb**.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT thanks, the picture you test in your app is on your computer ? or on Internet ?

Comment: What size/dimensions the images are?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz from 100kb to 2mb is the image some of them are repetitive and the pics are uploaded on Internet.

Comment: @Ali Malek, all pictures are in the Assets folder of app, the memory use is about 50mb.

Comment: Hello @AliMalek , please did you somehow solved your problem? I'm in the same situation right now. App is crashing when user drags the scroller and scrolls down fast.

Comment: @MichalKrchnavy Hi, yes you should read this [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization](ListView and GridView data virtualization) section. see this link for example of an a collection [Data Virtualazation Example](https://www.win-nevis.com/topic/207-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-data-virtualization-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-isupportincrementalloading/).
I will describe the the whole later here.